# Windows10アップデート後に、VirtualBox で仮想マシンが起動できなくなってしまいました。

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtualbox

Windows 10 20H2 アップデートを行ったのですが、VirtualBoxで仮想環境に利用していたホストオンリーアダプタがWindows側で消えており、新たな付番がされたアダプタに変わっていました。
そのため、アップデート前の仮想環境が起動できなくなってしまいました。

起動できるようにしたいのですが、今までのホストオンリーアダプタをWindowsで手動設定するしかないでしょうか？

**補足**

- VirtualBoxで、Windowsアップデート前の設定をバックアップはしていません。Windowsもバックアップなしです。
- Windowsで新たな付番がされて設定されていたアダプタはVirtualBox側にもあり、それを除去した上でVirtualBox自体をアンインストール＆再インストールしてみても起動できませんでした。その結果、Windows側ではホストオンリーアダプタは何もない状態になりました。

エラー内容を追記します。

```
Failed to open/create the internal network 'HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter' (VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND).
```

以上です。情報提供いただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

VirtualBox を起動した後、「ファイル」→「ホストネットワークマネージャー」を起動することでホストオンリーアダプターの管理ができます。
こちらで作成・削除を行うことで、Windows ホスト側の「ネットワーク接続」設定でもアダプタが追加・削除されます。

以前のアダプタが何らかの原因で削除された後も、仮想マシンの設定で (削除された) アダプタを指定したままの状態になっており起動に失敗しているのかもしれません。

前述のホストネットワークマネージャーからアダプターを作成し直して、仮想マシンの個別の設定も確認してみてください。

**仮想マシンの設定画面:**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

参考までに、デフォルトで作成されるホストオンリーアダプターの設定画面も載せておきます。

**ホストネットワークアダプター 設定画面:**

アダプター タブ

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

DHCPサーバー タブ

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 教えて頂いたように、Virtual Boxの方からアダプタを削除→作成しWindowsを再起動したら起動できました。ありがとうございました。